# nginx прочитать путь из файла

Tags: nginx

скажите может ли nginx прочитать файл и использовать его содержимое в конфигурации?Речь о чем, есть файл с текстом "../../backend/web" это тот путь который мне нужен, при переходе по имени файла он его скачивает, а надо чтобы он выполнил команду по переходу в указанную директорию.Скажите есть ли вообще такой механизм у nginx?интернет вразумительного ответа не дал

Comment: Что значит «выполнил команду по переходу»? В целом все настройки nginx читает при запуске. Опишите полностью задачу.

Comment: @Alexey Ten Спасибо за отклик.задача следующая.у меня есть готовая конфигурация(разворачиваю тестовый сервер). конфу прислали разрабы.установил nginx подсунул конфу, вроде лендинг открылся, но в админку не переходит(404).а в файлах проекта лежит этот файл с текстом  "../../backend/web" это тот путь который мне нужен. не могли же они просто этот файл для справки туда положить, вот я и подумал, что он принимает активную роль в переходе в админку(может я и не прав)

Comment: Вангую что это изначально был симлинк (symlink). Вы на винде разворачиваете что ли?

Comment: @Alexey Ten нет. на убунту.я с убунту только начал.могу только LEMP LAMP установить и простейшие операции в консоли.силинк я так понял ссылка на файл.подскажите как мне реализовать симлинк на этот файл в конфиге nginx?

Comment: Попросите разработчиков прислать правильную конфигурацию в которой симлинки не превращаются в файлы. Или датб инструкцию как разворачивать их конфиг.

Comment: @Alexey Ten был бы очень рад так сделать. но руководство расторгло договорные отношения с компанией...или просто не хотят давать их контактов...иными словами приходится работать с тем что есть(вот я и погряз с этой проблемой(

Answer (score 0):

@Alexey Ten Спасибо за помощь.Подсказал куда копать.
проблему решил вводом команды:

```
ln -s ../../backend/web /var/www/sjecproject.fvds.ru/frontend/web/admin
```